# Retrieve list all Labels and their job names from Talend Administration Center using MetaServlet API

Tags: talend

I want to retrieve list of all labels and their job names from TAC (Talend Administration Center)
preferably using Metaservlet API.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: which version of Talend are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the metaservlet API to query the list of tasks, with either of these commands:

```
{
  "actionName": "getTasksRelatedToJobs",
  "authPass": "admin",
  "authUser": "admin@company.com"
}
```

or

```
{
  "actionName": "listTasks",
  "authPass": "admin",
  "authUser": "admin@company.com",
  "fastMode": "true"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also tried below and it gives all the info that i need.

`{
  "actionName": "listProjects",
  "authPass": "xxx",
  "authUser": "xxx",
  "onlyActive": true,
  "onlyGit": false,
  "onlySvn": false,
  "withReference": false
}`